# Buffon noodle problem gives theoretical issues

Tags: probability-theory, geometric-probability

Let $\Gamma$ be a rectifiable curve in plane, having length $l$. Denote by $X_{\Gamma}$ the random variable that represents the number of crossings between $\Gamma$ and a grid of $d$-spaced parallel lines, where $d$ is a positive real number.

We can approximate $\Gamma$ by a sequence of broken lines having its vertices on $\Gamma$. More precisely we want this sequence to satisfy:

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sup_{x\in\Gamma_n}\inf_{y\in\Gamma} ||x-y||=0$. (1)

Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}(X_{\Gamma_n})=\mathbb{E}(X)$, where $X_{\Gamma_n}$ the random variable is the number of crossing between $\Gamma_n$ and the grid described in the statement.

These things appear to be "obvious" for those who wrote about the Buffon Noodle problem, but for me it's hard to prove them...

Comment: (i) is false, for example if $\Gamma$ is eight-shaped, the $\Gamma_n$ may approximate only one of the eyes.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I don't see why...

Comment: Did you check the papers by Ramaley and by Klein and Rota which were indicated to you in one of your previous questions on this exact problem?

Comment: Of course. They don't say nothing about the profound details on that problem.... But they helped me seeing the main idea